# Hosting Symfony 4 app with EasyDeployBundle on server without /usr/local/bin/composer

Tags: symfony, deployment, symfony4, ovh

For a Symfony 4 app I have chosen a Web Cloud plan from the hosting provider [OVH](https://www.ovh.com).

For the deployment I have decided to use the [EasyDeployBundle](https://github.com/EasyCorp/easy-deploy-bundle) which looks very promising. This is my config file:

```
<?php

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyDeployBundle\Deployer\DefaultDeployer;

return new class extends DefaultDeployer
{
    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->getConfigBuilder()
            ->server('ovh')
            ->deployDir('directory/path/at/server')
            ->repositoryUrl('git@github.com:foo/bar.git')
            ->repositoryBranch('master')
        ;
    }
}
```

I have `.ssh/config` file with the following entry:

```
Host ovh
    Hostname sshcloud.foobar.hosting.ovh.net
    Port 12345
    User foobar
```

Note: all values are dummies, just for illustrational purposes.

When I run:

```
php bin/console deploy --dry-run -v
```

everything goes fine, but when I actually try to deploy I get the following error:

> The command "ssh ovh 'which /usr/local/bin/composer'" failed.

The problem is that I have no write-access to the directory `/usr/local/bin/` on the server. The `composer.phar` is in my home directory and I can't move it to the provisioned destination.

Is there any possibility to tell `EasyDeployBundle` to look for `composer` in another directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should really read the manuals, in particular when I'm linking them in my question.

There is a method `remoteComposerBinaryPath` that accepts custom path to `composer`. I have amended the method `configure` like this:

```
public function configure()
{
    return $this->getConfigBuilder()
        ->server('ovh')
        ->deployDir('directory/path/at/server')
        ->repositoryUrl('git@github.com:foo/bar.git')
        ->repositoryBranch('master')
        ->remoteComposerBinaryPath('composer.phar')
    ;
}
```

On the server I created `.bashrc` in my home folder and added the line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/foobar
```

and now the deployment is passing this hurdle.

I have now another problem, but at least this one is solved and maybe the answer can help other people too.